# How to split an email in Python after '@'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code but when you insert an email, the domain does not print fully. Can someone please explain what is wrong with the code and if there is a faster option? (I am new to Python)

```
email = input ('Enter your email address: ').strip()

at = email.find ('@')
after_at = email.find ('  ' , at)
host = email [at+1 : after_at]

print (host)
```

> Ex. abc@gmail.com > gmail.co

Comment: `_, host = email.split('@')`.

Comment: there is the split function you can call strings: email.split("@"), does this work?

Comment: To explain your code, `email.find('  ', at)` is looking for two spaces in the string.  You probably did not type two spaces, so the string was not found.  In that case, `find` returns -1.  Saying `str[xxx:-1]` in Python means "up through the next to the last letter".  Hence, `gmail.co`.

Comment: @TimRoberts how do I format the code so it doesn't return the value of '-1'?

Comment: If you want EVERYTHING after the '@', then you don't need another find.  Just do `host = email[at+1:]`.  But the `split` proposals are a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `str.split`:

`domain = email.split('@')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
extract_username(user_name):
at = user_name.split("@")
return (at[0])
```

[0] this will post everything before the @
[1] this will post everything before the @

Hope this helps, sorry its taken a year to respond